# Add row on the gridview android

Tags: android, gridview

How to add another 1 full-width row on the top of the Grid view that is not divided into two?the content was same but the image would be display on right. here's the link to the tutorial i followed : [link to the tutorial](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/) i will mark this answer immediately for those who can solve this thanks!

Comment: take a look this github project. https://github.com/munix/GridViewHeader

Comment: kind of. But it included sample project. You just need GridView class. Or if you don't use this project, search gridview header.

Comment: i dont know how to do it. can you help me?

Comment: I think U want only one column in one row

Comment: exactly as this [link here](https://github.com/munix/GridViewHeader) but i dont know how to get that header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just make a change in Xml, in gridview jst change with  android:numColumns="1"